# Qt rendering using OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl, qml

I'm working on a QML application for an embedded platform which includes a GridView widget containing images. It's important for me that scrolling through the GridView will be smooth and will not put load on the CPU. Can I expect Qt to use OpenGL to render the GridView?

Comment: As far as I know about Qt QML you can use shaders (there are examples on the Qt site) ... I guess some OpenGl rendering is involved.

Comment: Shaders will come with QtQuick 2.0 (Qt 5.0) or you have to use QtQuick3D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced with the same problem.

```
QApplication::setGraphicsSystem(QLatin1String("opengl"));
```

haven`t work for me. So i set the OGWidget as a viewport:

```
QDeclarativeView mainwindow;
mainwindow.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("./qml/app.qml"));
QGLFormat format = QGLFormat(QGL::DirectRendering); // you can play with other rendering formats like DoubleBuffer or SimpleBuffer
format.setSampleBuffers(false);
QGLWidget *glWidget = new QGLWidget(format);
glWidget->setAutoFillBackground(false);
mainwindow.setViewport(glWidget);
```

and do not forget to add opengl in *.pro file.

Comment: which qt version did you use?

Comment: It was latest version at the moment. AFAIR, 4.6 with qtquick 1.0

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your platform use

```
QApplication::setGraphicsSystem(QLatin1String("opengl"));
```

or (Symbian)

```
QApplication::setGraphicsSystem(QLatin1String("openvg"));
```

before you instantiate the QApplication object.

Answer (score 2):

By default Qt does not use the OpenGL render backend. You can enforce it by using a QGlWidget. In your case, as you want to use a stock widget, you can set the render backend as a command line option:

```
<binary name> -graphicssystem opengl
```

Comment: ["-graphicssystem" option was deleted from Qt5](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41265)